# Unhandled IOException Inside Java List.stream.forEach Lambda Expression

Tags: java, file, exception, lambda, java-stream

I am using the Stream API introduced in Java 8 to run a method for each string in a list.

```
public boolean initFile() throws IOException
{
    if (this.outFile.exists()) {
        this.outFile.delete();
    }
    return this.outFile.createNewFile();
}

public void writeStringToFile(String str, boolean addNewLine) throws IOException
{
    if (this.mode != FileMode.READ) {
        if (this.initFile()) {
            FileWriter fileWriter;
            if (this.mode == FileMode.APPEND)
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile.getAbsolutePath(), true);
            else
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            fileWriter.write(str);
            if (addNewLine)
                fileWriter.write("\n");
            fileWriter.close();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("IO Error: The file could not be initialized.");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Cannot write to a file with the mode FileMode.READ");
    }
}

public void writeListToFile(List<String> strings, boolean addNewLine) throws IOException
{
    strings.stream().forEach(s -> this.writeStringToFile(s, addNewLine)); // Unhandled IOException from writeStringToFile
}
```

As you can see, the method signature states to throw all IOExceptions and the writeToString method inside the stream has the potential to throw an IOException. However, the Java compiler is giving me an error stating that there is an unhandled IOException on the stream line.

Why would the exception inside the stream not get thrown like any other exception inside the method? Is there any way that I can remedy this without putting a try-catch statement in the forEach lambda expression?

Comment: What do you want to happen if an IOException throws? Note this has little to do with lambdas and rather regular exception rules. `Stream#forEach` and `Consumer#accept` do not declare to throw this exception.

Comment: can you update your question with your initFile method declaration

Comment: I have added the initFile method. Note that all IOExceptions are thrown intentionally by design.

Comment: See also [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html).

Comment: Your code is illogical. You delete the file if it exists, so there is no point in supporting an append mode as you are always appending to a new file after `initFile()`. On the other hand, as you are actually *always* creating a new file, you don’t need the `initFile()` method at all, `new FileWriter(…)` will do exactly that. In other words, when your mode is not `APPEND` you are potentially deleting a file, creating a new file, implicitly deleting it again and creating a new file…

Comment: Holger, I knew the logic in the initFile method was flawed. I have since fixed it. It was not the focus of the question which is why I left it out entirely in the beginning. It has since been dealt with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use try catch in you writeListToFile method like this:

```
  public void writeListToFile(List<String> strings, boolean addNewLine) throws Exception {
    strings.stream().forEach(s -> {
        try {
            writeStringToFile(s, addNewLine);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //you can Log it immediately or throw ex;
            Logger.getLogger(C.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
    // Unhandled IOException from writeStringToFile
}
```

why?
look at this point s -> {}.Here {} means that compiler make new Interface (Consumer)

```
 void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action);
```

and new Class implements this interface and pass s parameter to it's accept method.Can you throw Exception of new Class in your method? No.So you have to try catch of every item of foreach

Comment: I have a very naive understanding of the Stream API as a whole. You seem to be knowledgable about the underlying processes which, to me, are a bit of a blackbox. Do you have any good, layman resources on consumers/suppliers/predicates/etc.?

Comment: google new in java 8.read subjects.research what you stucked and write blog to fully understand.When you write blog you will have to teach somebody and have to know subject much more clear

Answer (score 3):

Don’t reinvent the wheel. Use the features offered by the Java API.

```
public void writeListToFile(List<String> strings, boolean addNewLine) throws IOException
{
  if(this.mode == FileMode.READ)
      throw new IOException("Cannot write to a file with the mode FileMode.READ");

  Files.write(outFile.toPath(), addNewLine? strings:
      Collections.singleton(strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining())),
    this.mode==FileMode.APPEND? StandardOpenOption.APPEND: StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

[`Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) will write all lines of an `Iterable` (which includes `Collection`s) and that’s it. Your obstacle of supporting the `addNewLine` option can be solved by collecting all `String`s into one in the case, `addNewLine` is `false`, hence, there will be no line-feeds between them then. Otherwise, `Files.write` will append line-feeds to every string.

There is no point in manually dealing with testing for the existence of files or trying to delete or create them. Regardless of whether you create your own `Writer` or use `Files.write`, these implementations will already report failures regarding existence/non-existence or failed attempts of creating the target file via `IOException`s, so you don’t need to do it yourself.

Even worse, whatever `File.exists()`, `File.delete()`, or `File.createNewFile()` may return, is already an outdated information upon your subsequent I/O operation, e.g. creating/using a `Writer`, and does not guaranty anything about whether the subsequent operation will succeed or fail.